# Comparing two instances of XML for changes

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement where i want to keep/track changes to base XML document .
For this i have to figure out a most efficient  way to keep track of all the changes done to the base XML structure and keep those changes in a different fomat(xml).
My input source can be of both type that is SAX and DOM .How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It might be easiest to use a tool like `diff` and parse the output that implementing a diff method yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) has exactly this functionality:

[XMLTestCase.compareXML()](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/XMLTestCase.html#compareXML%28org.w3c.dom.Document,%20org.w3c.dom.Document%29) has both DOM and SAX versions.  Use `DetailedDiff` to get a list of all differences between the two XMLs.  Convert this diff object to your own representation if needed.

XMLUnit is nice because it can treat *similar* XML documents (such as whitespace, sibling order, namespace prefixes) as the same if you want.

Answer (score 1):

A commercial product that probably does everything you want in the area of XML differencing is DeltaXML.